Can I restrict the slot resouce in react big calendar to have only one data at particular slot time
I am using react big calendar to display the events in calendar format (Scheduling the events).
I am using drag and drop (inside the calendar as well as drag from outside the calendar).
In x-axis I am slot1 and slot2 so on and on y-axis I am using timeSlot.
What I want is to have a single event in resource with particular timeSlot.
for Example:
slot1 and timeSlot(10 am to 11 am)only one data.
slot1 and timeSlot(11 am to 12am )only one data.
slot2 and timeSlot(10 am to 11am)only one data.
I want to use resourceAccessorId prop .

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
